# Product of two closed immersions is also closed immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ be a morphism between $k$ - varieties. I Is the following statement true?

> If $f$ is a closed immersion, then $f\times f\colon X\times X\longrightarrow Y\times Y$ is also a closed immersion.

(*Proof?*)

For an affine $Y$, the statement is simple; whether a ring homomorphism $A\otimes A\longrightarrow A/I \otimes A/I$ surjects, and it follows immediately since $A\rightarrow A/I$ surjects.

For arbitrary $Y$, take its affine open cover $\{U_i\}$, and consider morphisms:
$$f\times f\colon(f\times f)^{-1}(U_i\times U_j)\longrightarrow U_i\times U_j.$$

Since $(f\times f)^{-1}(U_i\times U_j)=f^{-1}(U_i)\times f^{-1}(U_j)$ holds(?), $f\times f$ becomes a closed immersion. $\square$

---

There is no confidence that the assertion on the last line is true, could anyone help me?

Comment: I think it would be better to use the fact that closed immersions are stable under base change and the composition of closed immersions are again closed immersions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @KReiser . Using base change, $X\times X\longrightarrow X\times Y$ and $X\times Y\longrightarrow Y\times Y$ are closed immersions, so is $X\times X\longrightarrow Y\times Y$, done. Thank you.